# Livewire Dom Diffing: Input loses focus. How to fix this?

Tags: dom, laravel-livewire

Consider the following Livewire view's blade template code where `$tags` is an array of strings:

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <ul>
        @foreach($tags as $tag)
            <li wire:key="tag-{{ $loop->index }}">
                {{ $tag }}
            </li>
        @endforeach

        <input
            type="text"
            wire:model.defer="tagInputValue"
            wire:key="tag-input"
            wire:keydown.enter="add()"
        />
    </ul>
</div>
```

Whenever a user presses Enter key, `add()` function is executed, which does checks for bad values (duplicate tags), appends the input value to `$tags`, and then resets the input value by using `$this->reset('tagInputValue')`. This process of tag addition goes smoothly.

However, I have noticed that the input loses focus after the `add()` method's execution (which implied modification of the `<ul>`'s inner DOM tree). This is bad UX and, of course, should be fixed, so leaving it as is is not an option.

During my research, I've stumbled upon [Troubleshooting section](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting) of Livewire's official documentation. It points out that an input losing focus is a symptome of DOM diffing issues. However, I **do** have `wire:key` in both `<li>` and `<input>` elements, and the set keys are unique across the page, as required by the documentation.

### What I've tried:

- Putting `<input>` outside of `<ul>`. It worked, the input no longer lost focus, but due to the CSS styling I need the `<input>` **inside** of the `<ul>`.
- Putting `<input>` before the `@foreach` loop. Surprisingly, it also did work, the input keeps the focus, but that's not an option either, because `<input>` should appear after all list items in order to input new tags after the existing ones.

So, what's happening with DOM here and how do I keep focus of an input if it's used as the last child of the `<ul>`?

Comment: Did you try adding wire:ignore to the input?

Comment: @digout what's the reason to do so?

Comment: I believe it is re-rendering the input. Livewire had some known bugs with siblings of a foreach loop. Plus, it's not valid html.. no matter what, I would not put an input as child of ul. Did you try wrapping it in an <li>?

Comment: @digout so your suggestion will be to refactor the approach to the code itself, and base my styles not on `<ul>`, but on the wrapper?

Comment: without knowing the diff library used by livewire, I would hazard a guess that it is causing issues by having ul > input. If it's not working like this, don't do it ;)

Comment: @digout Then it's surprising that moving the input to the first child of the `<ul>` resolves the issue, because it would be still invalid HTML, and if that would've been the case, shuffling the order would not change the outcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252274/discussion-between-rusurano-and-digout).